# Filter other comboboxes based on a first combobox

Tags: vb.net

How do I filter other comboboxes based in first combobox which is having same data as the others.

I am using visual basic 2010 and a ms access database which is connected with code. On a vb form I have five comboboxes and all comboboxes are filled with the same data with this code:

Private Sub loadsubject()

```
    Dim OleDBC As New OleDbCommand
    Dim OleDBDR As OleDbDataReader
    With OleDBC
        .Connection = conn
        .CommandText = "SELECT subject FROM tblsubjectBA"
    End With
    OleDBDR = OleDBC.ExecuteReader
    cmbsub1.Items.Clear()
    cmbsub2.Items.Clear()
    cmbsub3.Items.Clear()
    cmbsub4.Items.Clear()
    If OleDBDR.HasRows Then
        While OleDBDR.Read
            cmbsub1.Items.Add(OleDBDR.Item(0))
            cmbsub2.Items.Add(OleDBDR.Item(0))
            cmbsub3.Items.Add(OleDBDR.Item(0))
            cmbsub4.Items.Add(OleDBDR.Item(0))
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

The data are 
"America"
"Russia"
"China"
"India"
"Africa"
"Europe"

Now I want to create a code which can filter the other commoboxes i.e;

if I select "India" from the list of 5 as in mention in combobox1 then
other 4 comboboxes must not show "India" in the list

then

If I select "Europe" form the list of 4 because 1 name was already selected in combobox1 then the other 3 comboxes must not show "india" and "Europe" in the list

The same should be follow for all comboboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with visual basic, but you shall implement a selection changed event for all of the combo boxes, and remove the corresponding elements from the other ones when the selection changes, and add the ones that are no longer filtered out. This is a fast and dirty solution, but should work.